# UIActionSheet position on landscape and portrait

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad, orientation, uiactionsheet

UIActionSheet positioning is not centered when I open it in landscape mode. If I set bounds or change the frame. The contents inside the UIActionSheet which is a subview changes but the actual sheet remains in the same place which looks very awkward.

How do I move the UIActionSheet along with it's subview to the center of the screen?

Comment: i ended up using UIAlertView adding my contents as a sub view to the alert view.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following code so that you can put he UIActionsheet in the middle of the screen as you want.

```
        UIActionSheet *actionsheet1 = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Options" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Contacts", @"Employees",nil];
        actionsheet1.tag = 1;
        [actionsheet1 showInView:self.view];
        [actionsheet1 setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque];
        [actionsheet1 release];
```

Please check this code and let me knwo if you still have any questions.